# When get active current cell, clear content of another cell Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**What I want to do:**

My intention is that when cell "E14" is active, that is, it is selected, then the content of cell "J14" is deleted.

This function is activated with a trigger, since the onEdit() function does not work in my spreadsheet for some reason ...

This is my code:

```
function borrar_contenido_celda_subcategoria_anadir_visita(){

  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Añadir visita");

  //var categoria = libro.getRange('E14');
  //Logger.log(categoria.getA1Notation());

  var celdaCategoria = libro.getCurrentCell().activate();
  Logger.log(celdaCategoria.getA1Notation());

  if ( celdaCategoria == 'E14' ){
    libro.getRange('J14').clearContent();
  }
```

When I run this function in my editor, Logger.log indicates that it succeeded, however when I look at the sheet, it is false.

As this function is activated through a trigger, I have tried to run it directly on the sheet, however nothing happens.

Therefore I deduce that something in my code is not correct.

Anyone who can help me resolve this situation? I started to play JavaScript a few days ago so I am still very green, however, I am struggling to inform myself and do everything I can by myself.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a small flow in your code

You should modify the line

`if ( celdaCategoria == 'E14' ){`

to

`if ( celdaCategoria.getA1Notation() == 'E14' ){`

to verify either the current cell is `E14`.

Comment: This clearly solved the problem! Right, I completely forgot about ```.getA1Notation ()```... Such a simple thing ... Definitely thank you very much !! @ziganotschka